# Pandas dataframe check if left part of a string matches another entry in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following csv file:

```
Column1;Column2;Column3;Column4
A;B;6;6200
B;D;5;5000
E;F;6;5100
F;F;6;6200
```

Now I want to check, if **column4** always begins with a '**6**', if **column3** has an entry **6**. In case, where this does not match I want to **print a message**. Same holds for the case vice versa: In case **column4** does not begin with a '**6**', but **column3** has an entry **6**. Both columns are string.

I tried:

```
if ((df[df["Column3"] == "6"] and df['Column4'].str[0:1] <> "6") or (df[df["Column3"] <> "6"] and df['Column4'].str[0:1] == "6")):
    print("Error")
```

But doesn't work. What did I miss?

Comment: do you want to print message for every row that does not respect the condition?

Comment: when you say "print Error .." do you mean you jut want to return the rows where the conditions aren't satisfied?

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the type of Column4?

Comment: Both string and I just need to print a message if there exists a case that does not fulfill the condition.

Comment: A few things to note. In Python "not equals" is spelled `!=`, not `<>`.  In pandas boolean masks should not be compared with `and`. Instead, use `&`.  Also, note that  `&`s low precedence will mean the conditions will need to be enclosed in parenthesis.

Comment: Yeah, good that I asked, because I was sure that my way (besides not working) is not the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two boolean masks and check their identity:

```
out = df[df['Column3'].eq('6') == df['Column4'].str.startswith('6')]
```

*NB. assuming you have strings. If not, add `.astype(str) right after slicing.*

```
out = df[df['Column3'].astype(str).eq('6') == df['Column4'].astype(str).str.startswith('6')]
```

Output:

```
0       A       B        6     6200
1       B       D        5     5000
3       F       F        6     6200
```

##### printing a message:

```
m = df['Column3'].eq('6') != df['Column4'].str.startswith('6')
if m.any():
    print(f'Error: row(s) {",".join(m[m].index.astype(str))} are invalid')
```

Output:

```
Error: row(s) 2 are invalid
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, however your output is not what I need. I am not interested in those values fulfilling the condition. I just want to print a message error if there exists one case.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for clarity?

Comment: The exptected output in this case simply would be "Caution!" As there exists one case where the rule is violated.

Comment: Perhaps `if (df['Column3'].eq('6') == df['Column4'].str.startswith('6')).any(): print "Caution!"`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski This is what I want, but I get an error syntax error. Also, shouldn't it be !=, because I am interested in printing the message if there exists an case where it is not equal?

Comment: @PSt see the update, which is almost what Steven proposed ;)

Comment: Good catch.  It should be `!=` and `any()`. `==` and `all()` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=';').astype(str) # Your frame here

out = df.loc[df["Column3"] == "6", "Column4"].str[0].eq("6").all()
# out is True if all values in column 4 start with 6 when the corresponding cell in column 3 is "6", False otherwise.

# Example usage:
if not out:
    print("Caution!")
```

Comment: How can I check if out is not empty and then print an error? I am not interested in the actual output, I just need an efficient way to print the message if there exists a case violating the rules.

Comment: `out` should always be a boolean (True or False), which you can use directly in `if not out: print(message)`

Comment: But it doesn't work, no message is printed.

Comment: Edited my answer to include the printing ;)

Comment: I ran that code with that example file and no message is printed?

Comment: Did you enter in your actual dataframe in place of the pd.read_clipboard()?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':['A','B','E','F'],'Column2':['B','D','F','F'], 'Column3':['6','5','6','6'], 'Column4':['6200','5000','5100','6200']})
df.loc[(df['Column3'].str.slice(stop=1)!=df['Column4'].str.slice(stop=1))] #Select rows where first char is not the same in column3 vs 4

#  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
#       E       F       6    5100
```